Understanding an integrable almost complex structure
My notes only say that
"Definition  An almost complex structure is integrable if it is induced by an underlying complex structure."
How do I translate this into a formula? I am not sure why there are both a complex structure and an almost complex structure, how are they related?
Moreover I have the following facts

I don't understand what are they saying It's like something is missing in the statement :An almost complex structure is integrable iff the map d defined like that is/does what? They define a map but say nothing about it

What note is that?

Normally there will be a $(0,2)$ component in $d\alpha$, when $\alpha \in \Omega^{1,0}$. The note is saying that the $(0,2)$ part of $d\alpha$ is zero when the almost complex structure is integrable.

@ArcticChar I meant my lecture notes, that what I have as definition and I don't know how to write this definition is a way that I can use it in proofs. I understand now what the corollary is saying , but I am not sure I understand how does a one-form decomposes like that, should the exterior derivative of a 1-form be a 2-form (i.e. a (2,0) -form)?

@some_math_guy Here, $(p,q)$-forms have to be understood as $(p+q)$-forms with $p$-holomorphic components and $q$-anti-holomorphic components. Careful not to confuse it with $p$-covariant and $q$-contravariant tensors

An almost complex structure is simply a smooth choice of complex structure $J$ on each tangent bundle. This is a weaker statement than the manifold being a complex manifold itself since we haven't necessarily got things like holomorphicity of the transition maps. As your notes say, if the almost complex structure comes from an actual complex structure it is called integrable.
This name is because integrability of $J$ is equivalent to the $\pm i$- eigenspaces of $J$ which are usually denoted $T^{1,0}M$ and $T^{0,1}M$ being Frobenius integrable. This result is called the Newlander-Nirenberg Theorem and gives us a formula for integrability of $J$. Namely $N_J=0$ where $N_J$ is the Nijenhuis (lots of N names here) tensor:
$$ N_J(X,Y) = [X,Y] +J([JX,Y]+[X,JY]) - [JX,JY].$$
Note the other results you mention do not mean that $d\alpha$ is a 2-form (which is of course automatic) but are instead defining $\Omega^{p,q}$ as sections of $\bigwedge^{p}T^{*1,0}M \otimes \bigwedge^{q}T^{*0,1}M$ (so note this is talking about $(p+q)$-forms, see here for example). Finally as has been noted in the comments the condition they are claiming is that the image of $d$ on $\Omega^{p,q}$ lies in $\Omega^{p+1,q} \oplus \Omega^{p,q+1}$.
